# Return the list with the highest selling price for each seller for the year 2016. Do not use the Min / Max functions

Tags: mysql, sql

You have two tables in a relational database.

```
Seller table:
salesman_id (int)
seller_name (string)
```

```
Sale Table:
sale_id (int)
salesman_id (int)
sale_date (date dd / mm / yyyy)
sale_value (double)
```

**Return the list with the highest selling price for each seller for the year 2016.**

**Do not use the Min / Max functions.**

Comment: Can you specify the output format? It a bit vague when you say return the list. Not sure what’s the specification of the list here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the logic below. This would work in MySQL v8 and above.

```
 Select
    S2.*,
    S1.*
    from
    (Select 
     Sale.*,
     RANK() over(partition by Salesman_id order by sale_value desc) As rnk
   from Sale
    where year(Sale_date) = 2016) S1
   JOIN Seller S2
   ON S1.Salesman_id = S2.Salesman_id
   WHERE S1.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: In case of downvote, would appreciate any specific feedback for improvement. As community of coders, feedback based constructive criticism is welcome so that we get an opportunity to work on improving ourselves.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372166/we-are-not-a-code-writing-service-comments-are-they-the-good-the-bad-or-the-u